# Insert value to the dynamic generate multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, addition

I was looking, but I did not find exactly what I needed.

Source structure is dynamic generate menu array structure from mysql database:

```
array (
  2 => array (
    'title' => 'item',
    'children' => array (
      10 => array (
        'title' => 'item',
        'children' => array (
          14 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          15 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          16 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              23 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
              24 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          17 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              20 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          18 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          19 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          32 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              33 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          59 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          60 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              61 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
              62 => array (
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          67 => array (
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      12 => array (
        'title' => 'item',
      ),
      13 => array (
        'title' => 'item',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I need to pass all the records and add new value as needed to the current place where the foreach actually is. Now i can use this function for examine record to record:

```
function categorize($menu, $level = 0)
{
    foreach ($menu as $key => &$data)
    {
        if (isset ($data['children']))
        {
            categorize($data['children'], ($level + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

but have no idea how to add new value to the right place.
the output must look like this:

```
array (
  2 => array (
    'level' => 0,
    'first-item' => true,
    'title' => 'item',
    'children' => array (
      10 => array (
        'level' => 1,
        'first-item' => true,
        'title' => 'item',
        'children' => array (
          14 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'first-item' => true,
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          15 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          16 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              23 => array (
                'level' => 3,
                'first-item' => true,
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
              24 => array (
                'level' => 3,
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          17 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'title' => 'item',
            'children' => array (
              20 => array (
                'level' => 3,
                'title' => 'item',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          18 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'title' => 'item',
          ),
          19 => array (
            'level' => 2,
            'title' => 'item',
          ), ....
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using straight php or with a framework like Laravel?

Comment: I use straight php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use referencing and recursion to achieve your desired output:

```
function processTitles(array &$titles, $level = 0) {
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($titles as &$title) {
        $title['level'] = $level;
        $title['first-item'] = ++$i === 1;

        if (!empty($title['children'])) {
            processTitles($title['children'], ++$level);
        }
    }
}

$titles = [
    // The input data that you posted
];

processTitles($titles);

var_dump($titles);
```

Comment: one question.. where i can find more about $title['first-item'] = ++$i === 1; i never seen this before.

Comment: ++$i increases the value of $i by 1 before the === comparison operator is invoked. The comparison to 1 will return a boolean value.

`$title['first-item'] = ++$i === 1;` is a shorthand way of writing:

`if (++$i === 1) {
    $title['first-item'] = true;
} else {
    $title['first-item'] = false;
}`